# GregorianCalendar DST problems

Tags: java, calendar, dst, gregorian-calendar

If I take the time at the end of the autumn day light time shift (2014-10-26 02:00:00 CET in Denmark) and subtract one hour (so I would expect to go back to 02:00 CEST) and then set the minutes to zero, I get some strange results:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));

cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.OCTOBER);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 26);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

System.out.println(cal.getTimeInMillis()); // 1414285200000 : 01:00:00 UTC

cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);

System.out.println(cal.getTimeInMillis()); // 1414281600000 : 00:00:00 UTC (as expected)

cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
// or: cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
// both should be NOPs.

System.out.println(cal.getTimeInMillis()); // 1414285200000 : 01:00:00 UTC (Why?!)
```

Is this a bug? I know that Java Calendar has some strange conventions, but I cannot see how this could be correct.

What is the correct way to subtract an hour and set the minutes to 0 using the Calendar class?

Comment: Man it's weird ! just tried it and got exact same thing ! it's like it remembers it first value after the set

Comment: required comment about joda time here while I boot up my ide to check this

Comment: I think it's rolling the Hour value forward (or pulling the default set state of the Calendar?. Reversing the commands (setting the minute, then adding the negative hour) seems to work, but it's a bit of a workaround for such an obvious problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are the [comments to the similar "bug"](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6615045?focusedCommentId=13327706&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-13327706) from Java Bug tracker:

> During the "fall-back" period, Calendar doesn't support disambiguation and the given local time is interpreted as standard time.
>
> To avoid the unexpected DST to standard time change, call add() to reset the value.

This means you should replace `set()` with

```
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

Comment: [One more explanation](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7022766?focusedCommentId=12252112&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-12252112) of the similar problem.

Answer (score 5):

The link in [apangin's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527872/gregoriancalendar-dst-problems/22613210#22613210) explains the problem and suggest a solution. I did tried to look at it the hard way looking throught the code.

If we check DST_OFFSET before and after our set:

```
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET));
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET));
```

It prints:

```
3600000
0
```

Looking at the methodgetTimeInMillis we see they use a flag (isTimeSet) to check when recalculating the time in millis:

```
public long getTimeInMillis() {
   if (!isTimeSet) {
       updateTime();
   }
   return time;
}
```

The flag **isTimeSet** is reset to false when calling **set**. From the source of [GregorianCalendar](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Calendar.java#Calendar.set%28int,int%29):

```
public void set(int field, int value)
{
    if (isLenient() && areFieldsSet && !areAllFieldsSet) {
        computeFields();
    }
    internalSet(field, value);
    isTimeSet = false;             // <-------------- here
    areFieldsSet = false;
    isSet[field] = true;
    stamp[field] = nextStamp++;
    if (nextStamp == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        adjustStamp();
    }
}
```

So **set** reset the DST offset. [This line](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/GregorianCalendar.java#2041) gets the offsets:

```
zoneOffset = ((ZoneInfo)tz).getOffsets(time, zoneOffsets);
```

A [little down](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/GregorianCalendar.java#2165) the values get set:

```
internalSet(DST_OFFSET, zoneOffsets[1]);
```

And the time in millis is changed onnext call to getTimeInMillis.

As [apangin suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527872/gregoriancalendar-dst-problems/22613210#22613210) we should not use **set** after inititializing the date or we would force a sort of date reset. This is how is suggested in the post in the bug tracker of OpenJDK.

```
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

Better alternatives is using Joda Time. The author of this library has been working on new Java 8's date time api, I hope doesnt have this kind of issues.

Answer (score 1):

[`Calendar.add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) method must act as follows:

> Adds or subtracts the specified amount of time to the given calendar field, **based on the calendar's rules**.

So we faced here with mysterious calendar's rules. What is the calendar type we've got by `Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"))`?

Execute

```
System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET")).getClass());
```

I've got answer: `class java.util.GregorianCalendar`. Let's try to find rules of `GregorianCalendar`. I found them in [`add method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) (why here?). One of rules fits your case.

> Add rule 2. If a smaller field is expected to be invariant, but it is impossible for it to be equal to its prior value because of changes in its minimum or maximum after field is changed, then its value is adjusted to be as close as possible to its expected value

01:00:00 and 23:00:00 have the same distance, so both are valid by these rules.

Also please note next line in [`GregorianCalendar.add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) specification

> Adds the specified **(signed)** amount of time

It says you were using it wrong calling `cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);` Hence you have no one to blame that your `add` shows result only on next `set` invocation. But it *somehow* works; you can use it!

What's to do here? If you're OK that 2014-10-26 02:00:00 CET minus one hour equals itself - then you can just add stupid `set` after your `add`. Like that:

```
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)); //apply changes
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
```

If you want to see the difference after `-1 hour` operation then I would advice you to change TimeZone. `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")` (as example) has no daylight saving time offset.